# input box slow in VBA code

Tags: excel, performance, input

```
Range("C5").Select

mydate = InputBox("Please enter Date Must be 3Letters+Day i.e Jan1")
                  Range("C5") = mydate
```

the problem is if the excel is just opened its fast working to type the date in input box but if I tried to operate the code after time of working with excel data it very slow ....not hanging but slow (the step of typing the date in input box) after that the code running normal just after passing this step

So I have to restart my excel before running this code

```
am using Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

looking for your help

Comment: i solved it by adding Application.ScreenUpdating = true before inputbox then again i added  Application.ScreenUpdating = False after it now its not slowing down

Comment: Please add your solution as a separate answer to your question, and mark it as accepted